# One iPhone, two developer machines

Tags: iphone, macos

I switch between my iMac and MacBook when working on my apps. I've always used my iMac to test the apps on the actual device, but I would like to be able to do this from both computers. I cannot seem to use the profile on my MacBook as it does not have the correct Certificate Signing Request in the KeyChain. Is there a way to copy these between machines and KeyChains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been simplified for IOS4. All you need to do now is go to the organizer and export the profile you need and then import on the other machine.
[iOS4 Guide - Managing your devices](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/xcode/conceptual/iphone_development/128-Managing_Devices_and_Digital_Identities/devices_and_identities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH4-SW8)

Answer (score 5):

To export the certificate, see [here](http://macosx.com/forums/mac-os-x-server/309491-exporting-certificate-private-key-keychain.html).

In short, enter this into the terminal:

```
sudo /Applications/Utilities/Keychain\ Access.app/Contents/MacOS/Keychain\ Access
```

This will require your password. Once the Keychain opens, you'll be able to export the certificate along with the private key.